# Flutter "packages get" failes with error "Couldn't read file LocalFile..."

Tags: android, flutter, cross-platform

I have a Flutter project and from one day to another I could not run `packages get` anymore. It failes with:

> Couldn't read file LocalFile:
>   'LOCAL_FLUTTER_SDK_PATH\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-1.0.6\android\src\main\kotlin\io\flutter\plugins\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle\FlutterAndroidLifecyclePlugin.kt'
>   even though it exists. Please verify that this file has read
>   permission and try again.

Also building the app is since that moment not possible anymore, it failes with the same error.

My `pubspec.yaml`:

```
name: my_app
description: My fancy cross plattform app

version: 1.0.0+2

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.3.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_cupertino_localizations: ^1.0.1
  http: ^0.12.0+2
  sqflite:
  path:
  crypto: ^2.1.3
  flutter_typeahead: ^1.7.0
  image_picker: 0.3.0
  google_maps_flutter: any
  http_parser: ^3.1.3
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  intl_translation: ^0.17.7

flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/img/

  uses-material-design: true
```

Note that I created a new project just with the same `pubspec.yaml` file and there everything works fine. If you have any idea which in my project could cause this error, please tell me I will add that source code then, because the `pubspec.yaml` seems not to be the reason or at least not the only one.

I have the newest Flutter version (v1.12.13+hotfix.8)

Comment: Have you tried this solution? https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47933#issuecomment-574088246

Comment: I tried what you mentioned but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue. Whenever I run, flutter pub get, I got the following error

`flutter Couldn't read file LocalFile: .... flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle\FlutterAndroidLifecyclePlugin.kt' even though it exists. Please verify that this file has read permission and try again.`

So, I run these two commands:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub cache repair
```

While running the second command, I noticed this new issue:

`Failed to repair flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle 1.0.7. Error: 
FileSystemException: Deletion failed, path = ...\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-1.0.7' (OS Error: The system cannot find the path specified.`

Then, following this [Packages GET failes with The plugin flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/52739), I removed the .pub-cache folder in my flutter directory

After that, I run

```
flutter pub get
```

Finally, everything starts to work again.